# generate getter and setter lambda with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am new to using Roslyn and the truth is that I am finding it quite interesting, but when using lambda expressions I am blocked. I would like to generate a property with getters and setters with lambda, so it looks like this:

```
private string uiDescription;
private string uiDescription;

public override string UiDescription {
    get => uiDescription ?? Name;
    set => uiDescription = value;
}
```

Would it be possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are not lambdas. Those are expression-bodied members.

Answer (score 0):

I already found it, so I'll leave it here in case anyone is interested. Surely it can be done better:

```
var variableDeclarationDescription = SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("string"))
               .AddVariables(SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator("uiDescription"));

var fieldDeclarationDescription = SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(variableDeclarationDescription)
                .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword));

  
var descriptionBody = variableDeclarationDescription.Variables.ToString()+ " ?? Name;"
var resourceGet = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(descriptionBody);
     
descriptionBody = variableDeclarationDescription.Variables.ToString() + " = value ;";
var resourceSet = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(descriptionBody);

var propertyGetLambda = SyntaxFactory.ArrowExpressionClause(resourceGet);
var propertySetLambda = SyntaxFactory.ArrowExpressionClause(resourceSet);

var propertyDeclarationDescription = SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("string"), "UiDescription")
                .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OverrideKeyword))
                .AddAccessorListAccessors(
                    SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration).
                         WithExpressionBody(propertyGetLambda),
                     SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration).
                         WithExpressionBody(propertySetLambda)
                );
```

I hope it can serve someone in the future. Thanks

Comment: Adding a short explanation of what / why you did this would prove useful to anyone in the same situation as yours.

Comment: Actually, the situation of doubt occurs, as the user Sweeper has very well corrected, in the use of expression-bodied members.
So the idea is that anyone who wants to render those expressions will be able to use the ArrowExpressionClause part of the code. In this case, the rest would be irrelevant just to render it the same as above.
I hope it helps you, thank you very much.